# Trigger a function on WPF application uninstall

Tags: .net, wpf, c#-4.0, event-handling, nsis

On uninstall I want to trigger a function which sends call to server informing that the application is uninstall. How can I trigger the function on uninstall? My application is developed in WPF and the installer is created using NSIS.

Answer (score 0):

You can send a HTTP HEAD/GET/POST request to your server in your uninstaller with the [INetC NSIS plug-in](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Inetc_plug-in).

Not everyone is OK with this type of telemetry/tracking so your lawyers probably need to include some clause in your [EULA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/End-user_license_agreement)...